# How to send JSON message to SLACK?

Tags: bash, curl, json, slack-desktop

I have a following JSON file:

```json
{
  "blocks": [
    {
      "type": "section",
      "text": {
        "type": "mrkdwn",
        "text": "Success: ondrejdolezal93's workflow (<https://circleci.com/api/v1.1/project/github/integromat/docker-db-updater/628|build>) in <https://app.circleci.com/pipelines/github/integromat/docker-db-updater%7Cintegromat/docker-db-updater> (<https://app.circleci.com/pipelines/github/integromat/docker-db-updater?branch=main%7Cmain>)\n- Fix update version (<https://github.com/integromat/docker-db-updater/commit/9a5b8d61a5c79dabbb2a47bb68b33748034986aa%7C9a5b8d6> by ondrejdolezal93)"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I am trying to send a message using Slack webhook with use of `curl`.

My command is like following:

```bsh
curl -X POST -H 'Content-type: application/json' --data @message.json $SLACK_WEBHOOK_URL
```

The reply from curl is: `no_text`

Please, what am I doing wrong? JSON is formatted according to Slack API documentation.

Comment: not sure, but maybe try `Content-Type` (with upper case **T**) (if not a copy paste typo)

Comment: @Archemar HTTP standard states that headers are case insensitive.

Answer (score 1):

In the Slack API documentation, it clearly says that if you send an JSON-encoded body, you will *have to* transmit your API token in an `Authorization` HTTP header.  You are not doing this.

An example `curl` query is provided in the documentation (modified by indenting it, replacing the in-line JSON document by a reference to a file, and quoting the URL):

```bsh
curl -X POST \
    -H 'Authorization: Bearer xoxb-1234-56789abcdefghijklmnop' \
    -H 'Content-type: application/json' \
    --data @message.json \
    'https://slack.com/api/chat.postMessage'
```

See the API documentation here: https://api.slack.com/web